# Statically Resolved Type Parameters

Tags: types, parameters, f#

The following (simplified) snippet is taken from an application I'm implementing which consistently uses Type Parameters resolved statically.

```
type A< ^B when ^B : (static member MyMember : Unit -> Unit)> = {
  Field : unit
}
type TestA = {
  AField : A< BTy >
}
and BTy = {
  BField : Unit
} with
  static member MyMember () = ()
```

IntelliSense gives me the following error when I define the type of field AField (`AField : A< BTy >`) which is: ***The type 'BTy' does not support any operators named 'MyMember'***.

EDITED.
Declaring them separately works, but if I have a mutual reference and I **cannot** declare a third type to put in the top which contains the common Infos of the two types. What should I do to avoid this problem? Anyway, if I define below the definitions `let pluto = ("" :> obj)  :?> A< BTy >` it works, I imagine because both types are visible from the let binding.

Comment: Are these sorts of constraints even allowable?  This could cause all sorts of problems for interop as say the C# compiler can't implement them.  Also, from the docs page `Cannot be used on types.` for statically resolved.

Comment: Is there any reason not to declare them separately? E.g, `type A`, then `type BTy`, then `type TestA`?

Comment: @JohnPalmer `static` member constraints are listed on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233203.aspx) as a valid example

Comment: bytebuster is right. Recursive type declaration doesn't play nicely with static constraints. Put your declarations in order; it would work.

Comment: @bytebuster - but check the statically resolved page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd548046.aspx - it says cannot be used on types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your implementation @Tomas satisfies the question but there is some hesitation over the style of your solution because it does not respected the functional programming paradigm. I thought to a solution arising from the Type Classes implementation of Haskell. 
Interfaces, abstract classes, etc. have been implemented in order to allow the F# environment to “interact” with the .Net environment, for a reason of uniformity of style the use of code which implements interfaces, abstract classes etc. in a context where no need of interact with the .Net libraries, it is a “Overhead” in my opinion (although F# is a multi-paradigm language). This is the reason why I found the implementation of the Type Classes of Haskell very elegant. Below I implemented through F# the “Haskell Type Class” code to solve my problem.

```
type Operations< ^a> = 
  {  
    MyMember : unit -> unit
  }

type A< ^a> = {
  Operations : Operations< ^a>
}

and TestA = { 
  AField : A< BTy > 
}

and BTy = { 
  BField : Unit 
}

let it = 
  let BTy_operations : Operations< BTy > = { MyMember = fun () -> () }
  let A_of_BTy = { Operations = BTy_operations }
  { AField = A_of_BTy }
```

Comment: This looks like a fine solution too. It requires more typing than implementation that captures `MyMember` implementation using static constraints (you'd have to fill the implementation in `BTy_operations`), which I thought was the point of your question.

Comment: But keep in mind that **F# is not Haskell**. F# is a multi-paradigm langauge and it is designed to allow mixing object-oriented concepts like interfaces with functional concepts like records when it makes sense. F# does not support Haskell-style type classes and so people use different programming patterns to solve problems that you'd solve using type classes in Haskell. Trying to mimick solution that works in Haskell will not give you idiomatic F# code.

Answer (score 13):

To be honest, I'm a bit surprised that you are even allowed to use static member constraints in a type declaration, but as mentioned by @pad, when you put the declarations in the right order and remove the recursion, it works (although I'm not sure that there won't be other limitations when you move to more complex examples):

```
type A< ^B when ^B : (static member MyMember : Unit -> Unit)> = 
  { Field : unit } 

type BTy = 
  { BField : Unit } 
  static member MyMember () = () 

type TestA = { AField : A<BTy> }
```

Anyway, I think using static member constraints in a type declaration is a bit complicated. A cleaner way to do this would be to define an interface that clearly describes (and documents) the members you need:

```
type IMyMember =
  abstract MyMember : unit -> unit
```

Now, static member constraints can still be used to create an implementation of the interface from a type that has the required member, but does not *implement* the interface. Using this technique, you should be able to implement exactly the same functionality as with static member constraints on types (but in a clearer way):

```
/// Captures 'IMyMember' implementation from another type using static constraints
let inline captureMyMember< ^B when ^B : (static member MyMember : Unit -> Unit)> =
  { new IMyMember with
      member x.MyMember () = 
        (^B : (static member MyMember : Unit -> Unit) ()) }
```

The function will, for example, create `IMyMember` from your `BTy` type:

```
/// A type that contains field and a captured implementation of 'IMyMember'
type A = 
  { Field : unit 
    Operations : IMyMember } 

let it = { Field = ()
           Operations = captureMyMember<BTy> }
```

Aside, I used the same technique in an article that shows how to [write generic numeric code](http://tomasp.net/blog/fsharp-generic-numeric.aspx) and I think that it worked there really nicely.