# F# generic type constraints and duck typing

Tags: generics, f#, inline

I'm trying to implement duck typing in F# and I spotted that you can have a [member constraint in F# generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233203.aspx) as follows:

```
type ListEntryViewModel<'T when 'T : (member Name : string)>(model:'T) = 
  inherit ViewModelBase()

  member this.Name with get() = model.Name
```

However, the above code won't compile when I try to reference the property. I get a compiler error:

> This code is not sufficiently generic. The type variable  ^T when  ^T
>   : (member get_Name :  ^T -> string) could not be generalized because
>   it would escape its scope.

Is it possible to implement duck typing via a generic constraint?

Comment: Note that this is not really "duck typing", but rather structural (sub)typing.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There was a similar question recently where [member constraints were used in the type declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12881828/statically-resolved-type-parameters/12887778#12887778).

I'm not sure how to correct your sample to make it compile, but I would not be surprised if that was not possible. Member constraints are designed to be used with statically resolved type parameters and especially with `inline` functions or members and I do not think it is idiomatic F# code to use them with type parameters of a class.

I think that a more idiomatic solution to your example would be to define an interface:

```
type INamed = 
  abstract Name : string

type ListEntryViewModel<'T when 'T :> INamed>(model:'T) =  
  member this.Name = model.Name
```

(In fact, the `ListEntryViewModel` probably does not need a type parameter and can just take `INamed` as a constructor parameter, but there may be some benefit in writing it in this way.)

Now, you can still use duck typing and use `ListEntryViewModel` on things that have `Name` property, but do not implement the `INamed` interface! This can be done by writing an `inline` function that returns `INamed` and uses static member constraints to capture the existing `Name` property:

```
let inline namedModel< ^T when ^T : (member Name : string)> (model:^T)= 
  { new INamed with
      member x.Name = 
        (^T : (member Name : string) model) }
```

You can then create your view model by writing `ListEntryViewModel(namedModel someObj)` where `someObj` does not have to implement the interface, but needs just the `Name` property.

I would prefer this style, because by taking an interface, you can better document what you require from the model. If you have other objects that do not fit the scheme, you can adapt them, but if you're writing a model, then implementing an interface is a good way to make sure it exposes all the required functionality.

Comment: Probably way too late to ask this but won't the object expression in the inline method create a new object every time the inline method is called? Could this be considered a downside of using the inline method as an adapter to interface? Especially if the Name is accessed a high number of times.

Answer (score 6):

To make your original code work:

```
type ListEntryViewModel< ^T when ^T : (member Name : string)>(model:^T) = 
    inherit ViewModelBase()

    member inline this.Name with get() = (^T : (member Name : string) model)
```

So you have to mark the member as "inline" and repeat the constraint in the member function.

I agree with Tomas that an Interface-based approach is usually preferred in F#.

Answer (score 6):

> Is it possible to implement duck typing via a generic constraint?

No. Except for a few special cases F# implements only nominal typing where duck typing is not possible. As the other answers have explained, the idiomatic "solution" is to retrofit an interface onto all of the classes that you wish had adhered to that interface but, of course, that is impractical in most cases where you want duck typing.

Note that this limitation in F# is inherited from .NET. If you want to see a more practical solution akin to duck typing, check out OCaml's structurally typed polymorphic variants and objects.