# F# how to pass interface to a function?

Tags: f#

I have action data that looks like:

```
type IHasShow =
  abstract member show:bool
type ShowHideNotCompletedData       = {show:bool}
type ShowHideCompletedData          = {show:bool}
[<Pojo>]
type ActionData =
  | ShowHideNotCompleted of ShowHideNotCompletedData
  | ShowHideCompleted of ShowHideCompletedData
```

Later I am trying to pass ShowHideNotCompletedData or ShowHideCompletedData to a function, the function only cares for a boolean "show" member but cant figure out how to pass/cast it:

```
let setShowItem (data:IHasShow) negate item =
  if data.show && (negate item.completed) then
    { item with show = true}
  else if (negate item.completed) then
    { item with show = false}
  else
    item
```

But how to call this function?

```
let setShowFn = setShowItem (data :> IHasShow) not
```

Error:

```
Type constraint mismatch. The type 
    'ShowHideNotCompletedData'    
is not compatible with type
    'IHasShow'
```

Tried

```
let setShowFn = setShowItem data not
```

Error:

```
The type 'ShowHideNotCompletedData' is not compatible with the type 'IHasShow'
```

Is there a way to this other than copy paste setShowItem taking a ShowHideNotCompletedData and a ShowHideCompleted?

If it helps; the full source code is here: https://github.com/amsterdamharu/riot_redux_fable

The simplest solution was to not pass the data but only the bool:

```
let setShowItem show negate item =
  if (negate item.completed) then//simplified if statement
    { item with show = show}
  else
    item
//...

| ShowHideCompleted data ->
  let setShowFn = setShowItem data.show id
  { state with
      showCompleted = data.show
      items = state.items
      |> Array.map setShowFn}
```

I do still wonder how to define a generic type and pass that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your current solution, your two types `ShowHideNotCompletedData` and `ShowHideCompletedData` are records. They have all fields of the interface, but don't explicitly implement them. The solution is to make the interface explicit:

```
type ShowHideNotCompletedData(show) =
    interface IHasShow with
        member this.show = show
type ShowHideCompletedData(show) = 
    interface IHasShow with
        member this.show = show
```

Instantiate as `ShowHideNotCompletedData true`. For alternative solutions, you may want to consult some of the SO questions about duck typing, for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13011811/generic-type-constraints-and-duck-typing)

Having said all that: I have a hunch that your data type definition is a little too complicated. @robkuz has posted an answer that does without the interface. Your own suggestion to just pass a bool into the function seems even better in terms of modularity and testability.

Answer (score 3):

I must admit: I dont like interfaces in F# - not in general but I think syntactically they are a total desaster.
So I more often than not use inline functions with type constraints.
Achtung: using this kind of code will probably kill a dozen puppies or sort

First thing get rid of your interface and the implementation of it (which you have forgotten anyways ;-) )

```
type ShowHideNotCompletedData       = {show:bool}
type ShowHideCompletedData          = {show:bool}
type ActionData =
    | ShowHideNotCompleted of ShowHideNotCompletedData
    | ShowHideCompleted of ShowHideCompletedData
```

Then write that really crazy looking function

```
let inline show< ^T when ^T : (member show : bool)> (x:^T) = 
      (^T : (member show : bool)(x))
```

and apply it

```
let setShowItem data =
    match data with
    | ShowHideNotCompleted x -> show x
    | ShowHideCompleted x -> show x
```

Comment: I'm with you on the dislike of interfaces. Your solution is more idiomatic than interfaces. I'm not sure though whether it is the best solution for the problem at hand, the data type seems overly complex, but the OP did not provide much context.

Comment: Or `let inline show x = (^T : (member show : bool)(x))` type inference FTW :-)