# Overhead of Object Expressions when used with inline function

Tags: f#, inline

I loved the idea used in the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13012065/11101800). My understanding of it is that it is an elegant way of using an interface as a method parameter without having to implement the interface. SRTP is used for duck typing to adopt a type (excuse the OO term, happy to learn the FP one) to the interface:

```
  let inline namedModel< ^T when ^T : (member Name : string)> (model:^T)= 
  { new INamed with
      member x.Name = 
        (^T : (member Name : string) model) }
```

What confuses me in the code above which I took from the accepted answer is the runtime behaviour of the inlined method.

It appears to me that this method will create and return a new implementation of the INamed every single time it is called. As I asked in the comments in the linked question, would not this lead to a lot of pressure on the garbage collector if `namedModel` method was called many times?

I'm really keen to use this approach but I cannot dare go ahead with lest my understanding  of its memory consumption is correct.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin care to copy paste your comment as an answer so that I can accept it? The question is about the mechanics of the call and object creation and you answered that. Re the gc pressure: I don't disagree with your points.

Comment: Done, copied as an answer. I will remove the comment after a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will create a new object on every call.

But keep in mind the first rule of optimization: first measure, then optimize. Are you sure that creating an object on every call would be prohibitively expensive in your case? Have you measured?

Another thing to keep in mind is that in normal code you are constantly creating and discarding objects, often without even thinking of it. The .NET garbage collector is specifically designed to handle this.